# Create customized count function in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Hi I want to create a function to count the number of values in an array which have specific characteristic and need your help here:

Basically the list of array is like below (cut short a bit alr):

1111111
1111110
1111101
1101001
1011111
1011110
1011101
1011100
1011001

and I have a value in a cell A1 (let's say 1101001)

I want to count the number of values in the array which are larger than the value in cell A1 and the difference between a specific value and cell A1 has sum of digits <= 7

My code is below:

```
Function NumOps(Curr_ConFig As Variant, ListOfOptions As Range)

    Dim Array1 As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim C As Integer

    Array1 = ListOfOptions
    C = 0

    For i = LBound(Array1) To UBound(Array1)

        k = i - Curr_ConFig

        If k < 0 Then
            C = C
        ElseIf SumDigits(k) > 7 Then
            C = C
        Else: C = C + 1
        End If     
    Next i
    NumOps = C
End Function
```

`Curr_ConFig` is supposed to be cell A1. ListOfOptions is supposed to be a Range of the array in Excel.

Assuming I already create a `SumDigits()` function successfully.

Could someone point me to the right direction? Thanks

Comment: `C = C` does nothing

Comment: What do you mean with "a specific value"?

Comment: If C1:C9 houses the range of array then would it not be simpler to calculate cells larger than A1 as `=COUNTIF(C1:C9,">"&A1)`. Why use UDF?

Comment: The complication is that I want to count only values in the array which have this characteristic: SumDigits(Value in array - A1) <=7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details of your question are a bit unclear, but this should help:

```
Function NumOps(Curr_ConFig As Range, ListOfOptions As Range) ' assuming Curr_ConFig is passed in as a Range (Cell)
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0

    For each cell in ListOfOptions.Cells
        If CInt(cell) > CInt(Curr_Config) And SumDigits(Curr_Config) <= 7 Then ' CInt() converts a string to an integer
            count = count + 1
        End If     
    Next

    NumOps = count
End Function
```

Comment: Hint: If you have a range object, most times you can just write the object name to get the value of the cell. In reality, the Property ".Value" is checked in those cases.

For example, if you write x = Range("A1") and A1 has a value of "1010110" then x will have the value "1010110". x = Range("A1").Value is strictly equivalent. x would then be of type string.

If you want to assign a variable to a Range Object you would use Set x = Range("A1"). I that case, x would be of type Range.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The script is very helpful. I've posted a slightly more refined version which works with real data.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

The code that works:

```
Function NumOps(Curr_ConFig As Range, ListOfOptions As Range)

Dim count As Integer
Dim cell As Range
count = 0

For Each cell In ListOfOptions.Cells
    If Val(cell) >= Val(Curr_ConFig) And SumDigits(Val(cell) - Val(Curr_ConFig)) <= 7 Then
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next

NumOps = count

End Function
```